# Python CFFI doesn't copy typedef from cdef() into generated C file

Tags: python, c, python-cffi

I'm feeding a generated header file into `ffi.cdef()`, with a bunch of typedefs like this at the beginning:

```c
typedef enum
{
    LE_GPIO_EDGE_NONE = 0,
    LE_GPIO_EDGE_RISING = 1,
    // ...etc...
}
le_gpio_Edge_t;
```

Then I try to compile it:

```py
with open(args.api_name + '_cdef.h') as f:
    cdef = f.read()

ffibuilder.cdef(cdef)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)
```

But it generates C code like this:

```c
static int _cffi_const_LE_GPIO_EDGE_RISING(unsigned long long *o)
{
  int n = (LE_GPIO_EDGE_RISING) <= 0;
  *o = (unsigned long long)((LE_GPIO_EDGE_RISING) | 0);  /* check that LE_GPIO_EDGE_RISING is an integer */
  return n;
}
```

Which causes the build to fail, because the symbol `LE_GPIO_EDGE_RISING` isn't defined anywhere (or referenced anywhere else)

```
le_gpio.c: In function ‘_cffi_const_LE_GPIO_EDGE_RISING’:
le_gpio.c:494:12: error: ‘LE_GPIO_EDGE_RISING’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    int n = (LE_GPIO_EDGE_RISING) <= 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `ffibuilder.set_source` seems to place the type definition to the generated C file.

```
import cffi

ffibuilder = cffi.FFI()

tdef = r"""
typedef enum
{
    LE_GPIO_EDGE_NONE = 0,
    LE_GPIO_EDGE_RISING = 1,
    // ...etc...
} le_gpio_Edge_t;
"""

ffibuilder.set_source("package._foo", tdef)
ffibuilder.cdef(tdef)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)
```

See [documentation for `c_header_source` argument of `set_source`](http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cdef.html#ffibuilder-set-source-preparing-out-of-line-modules).